# Eclipse debugger and remote debugger not working

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, remote-debugging

I m using Eclipse Luna Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600-32 BIT
I have some breakpoints and remote debugger on which use to work as expected.

Suddenly it stopped working. I m debugging using Target runtime option.

Now , it does not stop at the breakpoints. Though in case of remote debugging , it connects to the port.
Verified that using netstat.
But it is just not stopping at breakpoints. I m using SUN JDK 1.7
Some times I get PERM SPACE OUT issue. 
Kindly suggest.

Comment: What is the remote application?

Comment: Its a eclipse plugin. I m debugging a REST service.

Comment: Did it work in other eclipse versions?

Comment: It worked with Luna version itself. Suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems (Whearat EclipseA debugs EclipseB):

1. The plug-in you develop in EclipseA is async to the deployed plugin the EclipseB take use of. This may case if the project can not build compleatly in EclipseA or a old version of your plugin is loaded by the EclipseB first.
2. The EclipseB has not enougth memory/permgen. So add `-Xms512m -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` to the Debug-Configuration's VM-Arguments.

Comment: * I was using -Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m  


* When I changed to -Xms512m -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m as suggested ,the EclipseB was not starting. JVMJ9VM015W 


* Initialization error for library j9gc26(2): Failed to instantiate heap; 2G requested

Comment: Also I ensured , plugin of EclipseA is in sync with plugin of EclipseB

Answer (score 0):

You can do few things:

- Refresh all projects code
- Clean all projects and rebuild them

If any of above activities will not resolve your problem then try to remove all projects from eclipse, remove all eclipse settings files and directories and import your projects again.

Answer (score -1):

I also faxed this issue. I resolved by go to your eclipse workspace folder->.metadata ->org.eclipse.debug.core  inside this folder there will be .launches folder delete this folder. I am sure this will resolve you problem.